# Adjust size and position of bounding boxes while keeping it somewhat centered

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I have a bunch of images with respective bounding box co-ordinates (x,y,w,h). Some of the bounding boxes are rectangular, so firstly I want to make them square while still centered on the region of interest. Using the following example of an apple, with a bounding box on the stalk, I'd want to expand the box to a square while still keeping it centered on the stalk.

[image: square]

Secondly, after I've extracted out the contents of the bounding box, I want to capture contextual information by increasing the bounding box size by *n* pixels and extracting and then repeat. After that, I want to shift the geometric center of the region of interest just by a few pixels and repeat the multiple bounding box extraction. Like the below image, where the differently colored boxes represent the different boxes I want to extract. The right image shows the small shift in center that I want to achieve.

[image: multiple]

I have an idea on how to do this in numpy, but are there any higher-level functions/libraries that would help me with defining the bounding box and manipulating it as such?

Comment: Check whether I'm right.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bjddv.png   https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2Hyn.png If it's your want, then I'll answer it.

Comment: Yes this is what I'm looking for. I've implemented something in Numpy, can you share your code so I can compare?

Comment: OK, wait a minute...

Answer (score 4):

I use this image to do the same effects:

[image]

---

The code and the comment(as description):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# 2017.11.25 17:10:34 CST
# 2017.12.01 11:23:02 CST

import cv2
import numpy as np

## Read and copy 
img = cv2.imread("cat.jpg")
canvas = img.copy()

## set and crop the ROI 
x,y,w,h = bbox = (180, 100, 50, 100)
cv2.rectangle(canvas, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,0,255), 2)
croped = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
cv2.imshow("croped", croped)

## get the center and the radius
cx = x+w//2
cy = y+h//2
cr  = max(w,h)//2

## set offset, repeat enlarger ROI
dr = 10
for i in range(0,4):
    r = cr+i*dr
    cv2.rectangle(canvas, (cx-r, cy-r), (cx+r, cy+r), (0,255,0), 1)
    croped = img[cy-r:cy+r, cx-r:cx+r]
    cv2.imshow("croped{}".format(i), croped)

## display 
cv2.imshow("source", canvas)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

The result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is great but does not handle corner cases e.g. `cx, cy = 0`

Comment: @Kinght 金 I wanted to request the same question as Vladimir, can you go ahead and update your answer to deal with corner cases?

Answer (score 0):

## Handling Corner Cases (Improved)

Hi, I just literally used Github Co-Pilot to Generate this code, which increases the size of the bounding box by 10 percent, and this one also can handle corner cases.

```py
# expand bounding box by 10 percent
x = x - (w * 0.1)
y = y - (h * 0.1)
w = w + (w * 0.2)
h = h + (h * 0.2)
# make sure bounding box is within frame
x = max(int(x), 0)
y = max(int(y), 0)
w = min(int(w), imw - x)
h = min(int(h), imh - y)
# getting the bounding box
face_image = frame[y:w+y,x:x+h]
```

Answer (score 0):

A Javascript solution with proportionate bounding box values:

```js
const expansionFactor = 0.1;
const x = imageWidth * boundingBox["Left"];
const y = imageHeight * boundingBox["Top"];
const w = imageWidth * boundingBox["Width"];
const h = imageHeight * boundingBox["Height"];

const left = Math.max(x - w * expansionFactor, 0);
const top = Math.max(y - h * expansionFactor, 0);
const width = Math.min(w + w * 2 * expansionFactor, imageWidth - left);
const height = Math.min(h + h * 2 * expansionFactor, imageHeight - top);
```